# Refrence a list from another list

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-designer-workflow

I have a list that automatically gets added to when a user completes a form (lets call this List 1) and another list with all people who are required to complete the form (and List 2). So when the user submits the form, List 1 recieves it. I need List 2 to be updated and change the 'Form Completed' column to be yes.

I have tried this already within a SharePoint workflow but I recieve an error.

Comment: What error you recieved ?

Comment: It just says 'Error occured' in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

InfoPath form service degradation. Users are unable to create new forms on SharePoint Online lists through SharePoint Designer now.

As a workaround, users may able to create new forms via PowerApps by navigating to the library settings within the web UI of SharePoint Online, selecting "Form Settings" and then selecting to customize in PowerApps.

You can check it in the Office 365 admin center>Health>Service Health, select SharePoint Online.

[image]

Details:
[image]